# How can I prevent a duplicate on Redux when using the spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am doing this:

```js
    case LOAD_PAGES:
      return {
        ...state,
        pages: [...state.pages, action.pages],
      };
```

And I have a component that every time I enter to it, it send the same data to the store so I am getting lots of duplicate data.

The pages array looks like this:

```js
pages: [
      {
        key: 0,
        menuName: 'Home',
        pageType: 'HomePage',
        dataIndex: 'HomePage0'
      },
      {
        key: 1,
        menuName: 'Employer Chat',
        pageType: 'EmployerChat',
        dataIndex: 'EmployerChat1'
      },
]
```

This is the React component:

```js
  const handlePageLoad = () => {
    if (siteById.data) {
      siteById.data.pages.map((p, index) => {
        return loadPagesAction({
          key: index,
          menuName: p.menuName,
          pageType: p.pageType,
          dataIndex: p.pageType + index,
        });
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (siteById.data.pages.length) {
      handlePageLoad();
    }
  }, []);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you dispatch `loadPagesAction` for all pages? What is your purpose

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have to render a menu list based on those pages.

Comment: So If I understand correct, each component is a page, and when the page loads, who wish to update the state in redux so that you change the menu?

Comment: seems like you are returning state.pages twice: `(1st)...state,
        pages: [(2nd)...state.pages`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

Check if there is an existing page in your state or not, if return same or else push

```
case LOAD_PAGES:
        return {
            ...state,
            pages: state.pages.findIndex(page => page.key === action.pages.key) >= 0 ?
                    state.pages :
                    [...state.pages, action.pages]
        };
```

Comment: Instead of using `findIndex` you could use the built-in array function `some`.

Comment: @NikitaMalyschkin, The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function, so there is no extra looping, we can keep it as it is

Comment: @VivelDoshi, so does the `some()` method. `findIndex` is not wrong in any way, but `some` is just the proper tool for the job.

Comment: @NikitaMalyschkin, yes you can say that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's "smart" way to filter duplicates.

```js
function filterDuplicates(array, areEqual) {
  return array.filter((item, pos) => {
    return array.findIndex((other) => areEqual(item, other)) == pos;
  });
}

console.log(
  filterDuplicates([
    { key: 1, name: 'test' },
    { key: 2, name: 'apple' },
    { key: 1, name: 'test' },
  ], (a, b) => a.key == b.key)
);
```

Pass array to first argument and equality comparer to second argument of `filterDuplicates`. I got this idea from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/7616528).

### TypeScript

```
function filterDuplicates<T>(array: T[], areEqual: ((a: T, b: T) => boolean)): T[] {
  return array.filter((item: T, pos: number) => {
    return array.findIndex((other: T) => areEqual(item, other)) == pos;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply using set, the duplicated element can be omitted.

```
return { ...state, arr: Array.from(new Set([...state.arr, ...newArr]))};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve your problem and here is how I would approach it:

Instead of using an array, store your pages in an object and use the already defined keys as keys for the object. You can use `Object.values(store.pages)` or `Object.entries(store.pages)` to get an array of the pages the way you did before.